# Переменная для проверки не помогает

Tags: python, классы

Я пишу класс матрицы. Следующий метод должен возвращать матрицу у которой строки `i` и `j` поменяны местами, причём `inplace` при значении `True`, меняет эти строки и в исходной матрице. `self.body` - двумерный массив (матрица).
Вопрос: почему переменная `inplace` ни на что ни влияет (матрица почему-то всегда изменяется не зависимо от значения переменной).

```
def permutation_of_lines(self, i, j, inplace):
    if inplace:
        self.body[i], self.body[j] = self.body[j], self.body[i]
        return self
    else:
        result = self.body
        result[i], result[j] = result[j], result[i]
        return Matrix(result)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По умолчанию Python создает лишь ссылку на объект. Вам нужно использовать модуль `copy`:

```
from copy import deepcopy

def permutation_of_lines(self, i, j, inplace):
    if inplace:
        self.body[i], self.body[j] = self.body[j], self.body[i]
        return self
    else:
        result = deepcopy(self.body)
        result[i], result[j] = result[j], result[i]
        return Matrix(result)
```

Либо, если в вашей матрице нет вложенных списков и/или словарей (других сложных структур) можно сделать так:

```
def permutation_of_lines(self, i, j, inplace):
    if inplace:
        self.body[i], self.body[j] = self.body[j], self.body[i]
        return self
    else:
        result = self.body.copy()
        result[i], result[j] = result[j], result[i]
        return Matrix(result)
```